# Как соединить строки в C?

Tags: c

Очень глупый вопрос, но решение что-то найти не могу, наверное это настолько очевидно, что никто не пишет об этом,

```
Serial.println('data: '.CONSTANTA); // Не работает
Serial.println('data: '+CONSTANTA); // Похоже вообще сложение байт
```

Как две строки тогда склеить?

Comment: а 'Serial.println' - это точно с? это не с++/CLI ? и CONSTANTA - это случайно не число?

Comment: Да тут даже строк нет. Один не сильно валидный символ и ещё нечто неизвестное. Си - это не паскаль и не php.

Comment: Где здесь С? Что такое `Serial.println`? С каких это пор `'data: '` стало строкой в С?

Comment: Почитайте The C Programming Language Кернигана и Ричи

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос задан явно не для C, а для какого-то другого неизвестного языка

Comment: @PashaPash У меня микроконтроллер Arduino, там весьма специфичный язык программирования, как я понял смесь C и C++, с ним и с языком который на нем стоит я имею дело с 9 июня, так что вполне возможно я задал вопрос некорректно, strcat работать к сожалению отказывается

Comment: у Arduino свой C-подобный язык, насколько я понял. Но и в нем строки должны быть в двойных кавычках (у вас в - одинарных). Сложение - обычный `+`. И есть подробный [хелп по сложению строк](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringAdditionOperator).

Answer (score 2):

Только создать новый массив достаточного размера и туда их по очереди скопировать, [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308695/how-to-concatenate-const-literal-strings-in-c) есть пример.

Answer (score 1):

> Как две строки тогда склеить?

Посмотрите использование strncat() [тут](http://lord-n.narod.ru/download/books/walla/programming/Spr_po_C/14/strncat.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Не вполне понятен вопрос. Вы спрашиваете как соединить две строки, а пример даете для вывода строки и переменой.
Если вам необходимо соединить строки, то почитайте про strcat(), а вывод строки и переменной можно осуществить с помощью printf().